# How to install and enable moving text extension in joomla

Tags: joomla-2.5

Please visit this link : http://breakdesigns.net/extensions/moving-text

I installed this extension using : Extension Manager > Upload package file. It's installed successfully.

But when i gave this text is modules = > {text =scrollig text }

It's not working in site.

please help me to find solution to add moving text in joomla.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check that you have enabled the plugin in Extensions -> Plugin Manager.
2. Edit the module in Extensions -> Module Manager and set "Prepare Content" to "Yes" in the Options tab.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for reply. how to check it is enabled or not?

Comment: In Plug-in Manager: Content - MovingText , it's enabled.

Comment: And "Prepare Content" is also selected? This is important as it's what triggers the plugin usage.